# Hammer.js and default child div behaviour

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I am experimenting with Hammer.js and what I have is basically this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is attaching a doubletap event to the parent div like this:

```
$('#parent').hammer().bind('doubletap', function(e) {
  alert("doubletap");
});
```

The alert works but what stops working when binding the doubletap event is the normal text selection of the child div, I cannot mark the text. How can I make the default behaviour of the child div stay when binding a hammer event to the parent div?

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly call e.preventDefault() to stop text marking from working, so I think the only issue thats preventing the default is your alert(). It makes it impossible to mark any text. Try console.log("doubletap") and use [Chrome Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging).